# How can a child ignore a UIGesture in certain circumstances and let the superview handle it?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, event-handling, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm implementing something similar to iOS's memory manager. It is a [UICollectionView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionView_class/Reference/Reference.html) with [UICollectionViewCell](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewCell_class/Reference/Reference.html) children. If you swipe horizontally on a cell, the parent pans left. However, if you swipe vertically, the cells move with your finger.

[image]

In my UICollectionViewCell subclass, I have:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame]) {        
        UIPanGestureRecognizer* pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didPan:)];
        pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        pan.minimumNumberOfTouches = 1;
        [self addGestureRecognizer:pan];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Unfortunately, now all the child cells will be handling the pan gestures. The parent never gets to handle them.

```
- (void)didPan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    CGPoint velocity = [gesture velocityInView:self.superview];
    if (ABS(velocity.y) > ABS(velocity.x)) {
        // Move the cell with the finger
    } else {
        // Let the parent UICollectionView pan horizontally
    }
}
```

I already know how to move the cell with the finger, but I don't know how to do the other case: making the child cell ignore the pan gesture and letting its parent handle it.

Comment: How about adding UISwipeGestureRecognizer instead of pan gesture?

Comment: @MohdIftekharQurashi The swipe gesture does not provide feedback while swiping. That would be poor UI. [See article](http://ashfurrow.com/blog/dont-use-uiswipegesturerecognizer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have your cell's pan gesture recognizer recognize simultaneously with your collection view's pan gesture recognizer.

There are a few ways to do this, but one way to do it is by making your cell the `delegate` of your pan gesture recognizer and implementing this method:

```
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    // Either just return YES to allow your cell's gesture recognizer
    // to work simultaneously with all other recognizers:
    return YES;

    // Or you can decide whether your cell's pan gesture recognizer should
    // recognize simultaneously with otherGestureRecognizer. For example,
    // you could get a reference to your collection view's panGestureRecognizer
    // and only return YES if otherGestureRecognizer is equal to that recognizer:
    return otherGestureRecognizer == <your collection view's gesture recognizer>;
}
```

Comment: In `shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer`, I `return ![otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]`. This should mean that any other pan gesture should take precedence over my cell's pan gesture. However, implementing this function had no effect - my finger still panned the cell rather than the collection view. I even tried returning a hardcoded `NO` and the result was the same.

Comment: Try returning a hardcoded `YES`, as I suggested. What is the result then?

Comment: Ah, I mistunderstood the function. Returning `YES` makes both the parent scroll and the cell pan.